# How does focus change via tab work in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have 24 text fields divided into 12x2, and I need to change focus "rowwise" i.e. from left to right via tab. But when I click tab focus-change has unexpected behaviour, it "jumps" from one field to another without any pattern. I suspected it has something to do with `objectName` and I tried to fix it but nothing happens. This is how I created textEdit field:

```
        self.textEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 131, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_1.setObjectName("textEdit_1")
        self.textEdit_1.setTabChangeFocus(True)
```

I'm interested in how does the `setTabChangeFocus()` method works, how it determines which is the next field to focus, in order to fix the issue.

EDIT: MRE

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(877, 857)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 91, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 131, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_2.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 171, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.textEdit_3.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 211, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_4.setObjectName("textEdit_4")
        self.textEdit_4.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 291, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_5.setObjectName("textEdit_5")
        self.textEdit_5.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 371, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_6.setObjectName("textEdit_6")
        self.textEdit_6.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 251, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_7.setObjectName("textEdit_7")
        self.textEdit_7.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 331, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_8.setObjectName("textEdit_8")
        self.textEdit_8.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 451, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_9.setObjectName("textEdit_9")
        self.textEdit_9.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 531, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_10.setObjectName("textEdit_10")
        self.textEdit_10.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 411, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_11.setObjectName("textEdit_11")
        self.textEdit_11.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 491, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_12.setObjectName("textEdit_12")
        self.textEdit_12.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 370, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_13.setObjectName("textEdit_13")
        self.textEdit_13.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_14.setObjectName("textEdit_14")
        self.textEdit_14.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 250, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_15.setObjectName("textEdit_15")
        self.textEdit_15.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_16 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 290, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_16.setObjectName("textEdit_16")
        self.textEdit_16.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_17 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 90, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_17.setObjectName("textEdit_17")
        self.textEdit_17.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_18 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_18.setObjectName("textEdit_18")
        self.textEdit_18.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_19 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 170, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_19.setObjectName("textEdit_19")
        self.textEdit_19.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_20 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_20.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 330, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_20.setObjectName("textEdit_20")
        self.textEdit_20.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_21 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 410, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_21.setObjectName("textEdit_21")
        self.textEdit_21.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_22 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 450, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_22.setObjectName("textEdit_22")
        self.textEdit_22.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_23 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 530, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_23.setObjectName("textEdit_23")
        self.textEdit_23.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        self.textEdit_24 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 490, 121, 31))
        self.textEdit_24.setObjectName("textEdit_24")
        self.textEdit_24.setTabChangesFocus(True)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 877, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Now, when I made MRE in IDE without QtDesigner, it works and I realized I have copied `textEdit` fields in QtDesigner and I assume that messed up the whole thing. Can you explaint how mentioned method works so I could fix it in my app.

Comment: Use Qt Designer to build the MRE but so that the code is not extended create Nx2 QTextEdits where N is the smallest so that the problem is reproduced, and then share the .ui or .py generated.

Comment: I added the mre.py

Comment: no external links, all the code must be in your question.

Comment: ok, pasted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting layout as grid layout, it will be fixed.

setTabChangeFocus flag only set whether QTextedit type 'tab' or jump to other widgets.

Without Layout, tab will jump in order that you've created, shown on designer.
[image: Example]

Therefore, change order shown on Designer, or use layout.

Without layout:
[image]

With Grid layout:
[image]

Comment: So it has to do with the order. I will use Grid layout then This answers my question completely. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I had this issue before too.